# How i can get image from printer scanner using javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to make node js script that allows to user to get scanned image from printer scanner

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: No, I don't have a code I want to know if it possible to make this script and what is    the javascript package can do this work

Comment: Scanning images? Idk but this might help getting started: https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your NodeJS script can run commands (as in command line), an easy solution would be to install and configure a CLI scanning utility, and run it using NodeJS statements, for example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var path = 'c:\scan\Quickscan.exe resolution 300 A4 pdf showProgress prodname "My product" scanner "HP Scanjet 3200"';
var fun = function() {
   exec(path, function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
fun();
```

Examples of such CLI utilities are [QuickScan](https://www.burrotech.com/quickscan/) and [ScanImage](https://www.masoopy.com/scan-to-pdf-with-command-line-under-gnu-linux/) but you might be able to google around and find many more. As long as they are properly installed, these tools will return run codes that you can wait for (like in JS promises).

Note that the way to spawn a child process might change depending on your operative system. Documentation on running child processes: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html